# Trying to get the genre of a song but failing

Tags: android, mediastore

I know its been asked before but i could not find a solution yet.
I am trying to get the genre of a song stored in the device's storage and with the code below my app crashes

```
public void getMusic() {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Uri songUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor songCursor = contentResolver.query(songUri, null, null, null, null);
    if (songCursor != null && songCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int songTitle = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int songArtist = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
        int songAlbum = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);
        int songData = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
        int songID = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        MediaMetadataRetriever mr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        Uri trackUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,songID);
        mr.setDataSource(getBaseContext(), trackUri);
        do {
            String currentID = songCursor.getString(songID);
            String currentTitle = songCursor.getString(songTitle);
            String currentArtist = songCursor.getString(songArtist);
            String currentAlbum = songCursor.getString(songAlbum);
            String currentData = songCursor.getString(songData);
            String currentGenre = mr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_GENRE);
            songs.add(new Song(currentID, currentTitle, currentArtist, currentAlbum, currentGenre));
        } while (songCursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do it:
First get genre_id:

```
           public String getGenreId(Context context, String genrename) {
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.getContentUri("external");

    String genre_id = null;
    String genre = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.NAME;
    String id = MediaStore.Audio.Genres._ID;
    String[] strcriteria = {genrename};
    final String[] columns = {id, genre};
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        cursor = cr.query(uri, columns, "name=?", strcriteria, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int genre_idCol = cursor
                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Genres._ID);
        genre_id = cursor.getString(genre_idCol);
        cursor.close();
    }
    return genre_id;
}

       public Cursor getgenre_TrackCursor(Context context, long genreID) {
    final String track_id = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members._ID;
    final String track_no = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members.TRACK;
    final String track_name = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members.TITLE;
    final String artist = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members.ARTIST;
    final String duration = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members.DURATION;
    final String album = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members.ALBUM;
    final String composer = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members.COMPOSER;
    final String year = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members.YEAR;
    final String path = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members.DATA;
    final ContentResolver resolve = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members.getContentUri("external",
            genreID);
    final String[] columns = {track_id, track_no, artist, track_name,
            album, duration, year};
    return resolve.query(uri, columns, null, null, null);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that it works, between the time of my question and your answer i finally got to make it happen